# Как сделать чтобы поля ввода были ровными?

Tags: html, css, форма

Делаю так

```
 <div>
  <span>Логин</span>
  <input type="text">
</div>
<div>
  <span>Пароль</span>
  <input type="text">
</div>
```

и получается такая форма
Инпут рядом с логином почему-то длиннее
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как выровнять их?

Answer (score 0):

У вас span строчный элемент один шириной в 5 букв,другой в 6 букв.Соотвественно один шире другого.
span задайте строчно блочную модель (inline-block) ,оттолкните  правый инпут маргином в право margin-right: ваше значение.

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте такую форму -

```
<div>
  <span>Логин</span>
  <input style="margin-left: 8px" type="text">
</div>
<div>
  <span>Пароль</span>
  <input type="text">
</div>
```

И играйтесь со стилями, ставьте margin разные , и подбивайте в соответствии с вашей идеей

Answer (score 0):

Вариант на **flexbox**.
Продробнее на [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox)

```css
div {
  width: 235px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Логин</span>
  <input type="text">
</div>
<div>
  <span>Пароль</span>
  <input type="text">
</div>
```